# Pegar dados de um array React Native

Tags: array, react-native, axios, array-push

Preciso pegar dados de uma `array` do servidor para mostrar ao usuário. A é uma mostrar como se fosse um `feed` de uma rede social, mas está mostrando os mesmos conteúdos repetidas vezes.

```html
componentDidMount = async () => {
    await api.get('postagens').then(res=>{
        this.setState({id_postagens: res.data.count});
        this.setState({posts: res.data.posts});
    });
    for(let i = 0; i<=this.state.id_postagens; i++){
        const {titulo, criador} = this.state.posts[i];
        this.setState({titulo,criador});
    }
};

render() {
    var valor = this.state.id_postagens;
    var i=0;
    var postagens = [];
      

    while(i<valor){
        const {criador, titulo} = this.state;
        postagens.push(<View styles={{flex:1}} key= {i}>
        <View style={styles.box}>
          <View
            style={styles.foto}>
          </View>
        <Text  style={styles.texto}>{criador}</Text>
            <Text  style={styles.tempo}>30 min.</Text>
          <View>
          <Text style={styles.titulo}>{titulo}</Text>
          </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.iconComment}>
              <Icon name="message-circle" size={25} color="#31788A" />
              <Text style={styles.message}>0</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        </View>)
        i++;
    }
    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View>
                {postagens}
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```

Comment: se código não é usual no mundo `React`, um exemplo é utilizar `while` realmente muito diferente, não estou dizendo que não possa funcionar, mas, é diferente do que a gente vê por ai. Na função onde você colocou a requisição e depois a atualização do estado de várias variáveis não dá tempo para depois executar um `for` ... tem algo de estranho no seu código e por isso dos problemas, [será que com uma edição poderia melhorar o entendimento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/464670/edit)?

Comment: Tente colocar esse contador fora do render, pq o react renderiza a pagina várias vezes e acho que a cada renderização ele está inicializando a variável

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, o ideal seria você criar uma função `async` fora do `componentDidMount`. Com a função criada fora, você simplesmente chama ela no `componentDidMount` deixando ele normal, sem ser `async`.

Dito isso, voltemos ao seu problema inicial. Geralmente no React quando você quer mostrar um array de informações na tela, você simplesmente faz um `map` nele. No seu exemplo, você quer limitar o número de itens renderizados, isso pode ser feito usando o método `slice`, assim você pega apenas a parte do array que precisa e aplica o `map` na mesma. Vale mencionar que você pode dar um `setState` com mais de uma variável e que o `setState` dentro de um loop não é algo desejável, e pode prejudicar a performance do seu aplicativo.

Acredito que o ideal na sua situação, seria descartar o `for` embaixo da requisição e realizar um `slice` junto com um `map` na variável `this.state.posts`. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
  getPostagens = async () => {
    await api.get("postagens").then(({ data }) => {
      this.setState({ id_postagens: data.count, posts: data.posts });
    });
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    getPostagens();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View>
          {this.state.posts
            .slice(0, this.state.id_postagens)
            .map(({ criador, titulo }, index) => (
              <View styles={{ flex: 1 }} key={index.toString()}>
                  {...}
              </View>
            ))}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

O ideal também seria validar se o `this.state.posts` está vazio para evitar erros. Recomendo você dar uma olhada sobre o componente `FlatList`, ela lida melhor com esse tipo de tarefa e seria mais recomendada no seu caso.

Comment: Eu tentei desse modo mas está dando o erro: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.posts.slice')"